# Creating MVC webservice with no timeout

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to create a ASP.NET API service that when called doesnt wait for a response from the webserver. Basically I have a long sql task that I want to run then when its completed send an email to the user to tell them the job is done. It needs to avoid server response timeout, so something that just lets the user carry on without waiting round. I cant seem to find a way in MVC to do this, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queue the task and return the response immediately.

Basically, your server-side handler (controller action, Web API method, whatever) shouldn't invoke the long-running back-end task directly.  It should do something relatively fast to just queue the task and then immediately return some indication that the task has been successfully queued.  Another process entirely should actually execute the long-running task.

What I would recommend is two server-side applications.  One is the web application, the other is either a Windows Service or a periodically scheduled Console Application.  The web application would write a record to a database table to "queue" the process.  This could contain simply:

- User who queued the process
- When it was queued
- What process was queued (if there would ever be more than one, for example)
- Status of the process ("queued" initially)
- Anything else you might want to store.

Just insert a record here and then return to the user.  At this point the web application has done its job.

The Windows Service (or Console Application) would check this database table for "queued" records.  When it finds one, update the status to "processing" (so other executions don't try to run the same one) and invoke the long-running process.  When the long-running process is complete, update the status to "complete" (or just delete the record if you don't want it anymore) and notify the user.  (Handle error conditions accordingly, of course.  Maybe re-try, maybe notify the user of the error, etc.)

By separating the concerns like this you place the appropriate responsibilities in the appropriate application contexts and provide the user with exactly the experience they're looking for.  You additionally open the door for future functionality, such as queueing the process by means other than the web application or running reports on queued/running/failed/etc. processes by examining that database table.

Long story short: Don't try to hack a web application so that it doesn't behave like a web application.  Use the technologies for their appropriate purposes.

Comment: I'm going to schedule a windows take like you said, I just dont like having a separate apps and would rather stick to a iis job is its possible. but your probably right here.

Comment: @user1238321: I'm not sure what you mean by "an IIS job", IIS is a web server not a task scheduler.  Web applications simply aren't designed for long-running processes.  They're request/response systems.  Receive a request, perform some minimal back-end processing, deliver a response.  In the event of a long-running process the job of any UI (think of the entire web application as a UI) is to simply invoke the process and return control to the user.  A UI should never be blocked by a long-running process, and web applications are no exception to that.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, I would queue this job and process it using another process outside IIS.

For example, this would be the flow:

1. User performs a request to your API to start the long task, but what API does in the server-side is queueing the whole task.
2. API returns a 200 OK response specifying that the job was queued successfully. *You may use Azure Service Bus, Queues, MSMQ, RabbitMQ, Redis or even SQL Server using a table to maintain job state.*
3. Some Windows Service, Azure Worker Role or a periodic scheduled task dequeues the task, processes it and as soon as it ends, it sends an email to the user to notify that the operation was done.